# how to call a custom function onclick() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to call a function on a  using jquery. This function needs to submit a form.
Is this possible?

The reason i need something like this is that i need to have the submission of form happen at two links ie the submission should happen if the user clicks on any of the 2 links. The values of the form are set in as hidden fields so there is no user input except the click on the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice based on what you're trying to achieve:
say you have two elements that should submit the form with the id's element_1 and element_2:

```
$(function(){
    $("#element_1, #element_2").click(function(){
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
```

If the elements are a link you do not want to be followed, you can append `return false;` to the end of the call, but if they're simply input buttons, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `return false();` should be just `return false;`. Unless you have a `function false(){ return false; }` declaration. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selector").click(function(event){ 
    $("form").submit();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.link').click(function(){
   $('form').submit();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function:

```
jQuery('#yourlinkid').live('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url     : submitform.php,
        type    : POST,
        data    : $('#yourformid').serialize(),
        success : function( data ) {
                        alert(data);        
                   }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to use the `event` method `preventDefault`, instead of returning false.

```
$('a.link').click(function (event) {
    $('form').submit();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```